# Does Multisite Manager work the same with sub-directories, or is it better to use sub-domains?

Tags: multi-site-manager, admin, subdomain

We have a site where we need to be able to control both front-end and back-end permissions on a per-site level.

Our site structure is as follows:

**Main Site / Main Domain:** All can access is ok
 
**State Site / Sub Domain:** Restricted access - front-end via cookies, back-end via permissions

They, for SEO reasons, would like their URLs to look like this:

**Main Site / Main Domain:** www.mydomain.com
**State Site / Sub - Domain:** www.mydomain.com/state

Does it matter if we use sub-directories, or would we need to use actual sub-domains for this? Or is there any other reason to use a sub-domain vs a sub-directory with MSM?

Answer (score 2):

I've done both. The only thing you'll have to consider it making sure your cookie domains are set correctly, depending on if it's a `site2.domain.com` or `domain.com/site2`. Otherwise, the MSM sites will function exactly the same.

Past that, at most you have the regular head aches that could come from migrating a site, including getting `.htaccess` rules set correctly, and possibly dealing with hard coded links in templates in layouts and content, but that could also be fixed with `.htaccess` rules if you know what you're doing. Also, you'll have to make sure the introduction of `/state` to your main domains URI scheme isn't in conflict with any existing routes that start with `state`.

Answer (score 2):

**Well, both things are fine in the terms of MSM.** You can create sub-domain as well as sub-directory also. **Just you need to take care is, about path settings at the time of setting MSM website.**

**And if you want to make SEO friendly then, yes sub-directory is the best option.**